# ¿Como se hace un setInterval con Ionic?

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic3, setinterval

Mi problema es que no se como hacer un setInterval en Ionic3. He puesto en el .ts de mi página lo siguiente:

```
export class ClickerPage {

public dinero=0;
public produccion=1;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  setInterval(function(){
    this.dinero+=this.produccion;
  }, 1000);
}
 ...
```

Y en la vista he utilizado:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="cash" item-start></ion-icon>
  Dinero:
  <ion-badge item-end>{{dinero}}</ion-badge>
</ion-item>
```

Pero no funciona, simplemente no se actualiza, no se si va en el constructor como he hecho, o va en algún otro lugar el setInterval. ¿Podéis ayudarme? Gracias!

Comment: Estás actualizando el valor de this.dinero, pero quizás tendrías que re-renderizar el componente para que se vea el campo, ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quien le interese he conseguido solucionar el problema con lo siguiente:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
 this.dinero = setInterval(() => {
  this.sumarDinero();
 }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `sumarFinero`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro **sumarDinero(){
    this.dinero+=this.produccion;
  }**